# Failed to compare dates via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to compare two dates which are in below format:

```
9/10/2014 5:22 PM
```

I have two such dates and i want to compare them.

For that i have written below code:

```
 var StartDateTime = ($("#dtpStartDate").data("kendoDateTimePicker")).value().toLocaleString("en-US");

 var currentDateTime = new Date();

 if (StartDateTime < currentDateTime.toLocaleString()) {
            alert("StartDateTime is less");
            flagValidation = false;
        }
        else {
            alert("StartDateTime is large");
        }
```

But actually when StartDateTime  is less than currentdatetime then also Its showing alert "StartDateTime is large".

Please help me.

How can i compare the dates correctly?

Comment: You're not comparing dates here, you're comparing strings. Use `if($("#dtpStartDate").data("kendoDateTimePicker")).value() < currentDateTime)` instead

Answer (score 2):

You have convert object to date format to compare and consider all components of date. for your reference (Check the hard coded minutes..)

```
if(new Date("9/10/2014 5:23 PM") <= new Date("9/10/2014 5:22 PM")){
  alert("StartDateTime is less");
}
else{
  alert("StartDateTime is large");
}
```

Comment: dhanyawad patil bhau :)